# How do I determine the Hg changeset that maps to the autofac release?

Tags: autofac

I am unable to see what changeset revision was used to build revision 2.5.4.724.  Sometimes projects will use tags or branches to manage a release revision.

Am I just missing something?

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

724 is the sequential changeset number of the revision in the public hg repo. Not sure how to get this from the command line, but in TortoiseHg it is shown in the repo browser.

We need to add this info to the wiki somewhere I think :)

Comment: Thanks Nick - since revision numbers are only unique to a given copy of the repo, it might be a nice practice to 1) publish the revision hash, 2) tag the release or 3) have a release branch. (in order of least intrusive to most).